# Can the topology of a quad mesh with irregular vertices be represented as a square grid graph?

Tags: graph, geometry, computational-geometry, mesh, topology

I would like to know whether the topology of a quad mesh containing irregular vertices (vertices of degree higher or lower than 4) can be represented as a square grid graph or not.

Ideally I would like to find (or build) an algorithm that takes a quad mesh in input and computes its topological representation as a 2D array.

For clarity I have made this example where I tried to depict the adjacency relations between the faces of a quad mesh with irregular vertices inside a regular 2D grid.

[image]

Provided this representation is correct:

- Do you think it can be generalized to other quad meshes with irregular vertices ?
- If so, would there be a name for it ?
- If so, would there be an algorithm to compute it ? (related to graph theory maybe ?)

Comment: Possibly a better fit for [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/). Very interesting question.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll try asking there as well.

Comment: The question is already on math: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3762616/can-the-topology-of-a-quad-mesh-with-irregular-vertices-be-represented-as-a-squa

Comment: Hi, it is not "already" there, I posted it on SE just yesterday following Anton's suggestion above.